# Visual Studio VB "Input string was not in a correct format" error at form design time

Tags: vb.net

In VS Studio Express 2017, 2019, and 2022 I get an error "Input string was not in a correct format" at design time when trying to inherit a form.  I can view the form I am inheriting from at design time, but not the form that is doing the inheriting.  There is no error line number specified and the call stack shows:

> at Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Conversions.ParseDouble(String Value, NumberFormatInfo NumberFormat)
> at Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Conversions.ToInteger(String Value)

At this time there is no code in the inherited form and there are no controls on the form itself since I can't look at the form.  Actually, I can look at the form if I remove the Inherit statement.  Also, the program compiles and runs correctly.

I am completely stumped and have no idea how to find the error.  All my searches have come up with run time errors.  I have a feeling it's a MS bug or a corrupted file somewhere.

Any ideas on how to find my problem?

Comment: This usually indicates an Integer is attempting to be parsed from a String, but the value was not a valid Integer. I would look for something in the Form's constructor that uses `CInt` or `Convert.ToInt32`.

Comment: I realize that's what the error means.  I revised the problem description to indicate that there is no code in the inherited form's code section and no controls on the form itself since I cannot look at it to add any unless I remove the Inherit statement.  I also added the fact that the program does compile and run in spite of the error and I can display the form.

Comment: Can you narrow it down to the inheritance of the form? E.g. temporarily stop inheriting it just to see if the error goes away?

Comment: As I stated in my edit the error does go away when I remove the Inherit statement and I am able to view the form, compile the program, and run the program.  When I put the inherit statement back in the error returns.  Just in case I wasn't clear before, even with the Inherit statement and the error the program compiles and runs, so this is turning out to be more of an annoyance than an error that keeps me from continuing since I can edit my form if I remove the Inherit and then add it again afterwards.  I think I will do a redesign to eliminate the need for the Inherit.